# UberSVN vs VisualSVN Server - Any experiences?

Tags: version-control, migration

I'm looking at [UberSVN](http://www.ubersvn.com) as a possible replacement to our existing source control package, VisualSVN Server.

There are a lot of UI benefits for the decision, including having the integrated web UI, administration portal and collaboration features.

The concern I have is what difficulties I'll face in migrating from VisualSVN to UberSVN and whether there could be any impact to our repositories. Any experience or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously uberSVN is still a very new product so I imagine experiences might be difficult to come by. You're not the first to ask this question though so I might be wrong about that!

The way uberSVN is designed, when you add repositories and choose the 'Import Existing Repository' option, the repository will be copied from the current repository location into the storage location you choose for uberSVN at installation time. That way we don't interfere with your existing VisualSVN installation and you can easily test the migration without risking breaking anything in your existing setup. When you are happy it works you can gracefully migrate from one to the other with very minimal downtime for users.

The one area that might take further thought is how you handle user account creation and authentication in uberSVN. If you can advise how many Subversion users you have now and how your authentication is currently handled I can provide a bit more info on the best way to do this. We have discussed providing some specific migration tools from other systems and it would be very interesting to know how you get on with this. Of course if you need any help feel free to update your question or to contact me directly.

Ian Wild,
uberSVN Product Manager, WANdisco Inc.

Comment: Looks interesting, but rubbish website - pretty, but I couldn't even find out if it installs on Linux, let alone uses ActiveDirectory user logins.

Comment: I wouldn't be so harsh as to say the site's rubbish. That's a little unfair to say the least. Also there are community forum and blog links which appear to have a good breadth of information.

Comment: I would have to agree.  There website is a great deal of fluff, their support articles need some work, everything I need should be within the support articles.  If I come up with a unique problem the forum is fine for that.

Comment: ok, I was a little harsh, it's a nice enough website, but its style greatly outweighed the substance. I'm a substance kind of guy (as I think most avn admins are) so the website isn't really hitting its audience demographic.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - Ok, I'd have to agree with you there. Still - big ups to the provider for making the effort to directly engage with [potential] customers.

Comment: There is a fair bit of substance in the support pages and community, but we can certainly improve things. All feedback is valuable, harsh or otherwise, so thanks guys and watch this space :-)

Comment: @Ian: great, that's what I like to hear - good luck to you. I've been looking out for a replacement for VisualSVN Server that runs on Linux for a while now.

Answer (score 4):

The repositories in VisualSVN are standard SVN repositories - you can go play with the SVN command line tools, I would assume (I would hope) that the same is true of uberSVN.

On that basis migration should be fairly trivial - absolute worst case is export and import using the standard SVN tools (that I can't remember at this time of the evening). Best case is liable to be just pointing uberSVN at the right folders...